# D3.js: Tree layout with variable distance between branches

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm developing a complex horizontal tree graph with d3 and the d3.layout.tree() function. Now I'm in a point where I need to display a list in each node with a fixed depth (e.g. 4), and these lists have variable height.

One way to manage this is to set a chart height so no nodes get overlapped, but I have to consider the case that all the nodes have the longest list. This makes the chart extremely long and visually ugly, so I wonder if it is a way to set the vertical distance between the horizontal branches dynamically.

I've tried the nodeSize property but again, it has to be the same for all the nodes. If there is no possible way to do this, how would you tackle this problem? I've already set a modal to show all the information, but these lists are mandatory and have to be in the tree chart.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you mean by vertical distance between horizontal branches https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#separation ? It says it can be used to set the distance between adjacent sibling, cousin...ancestor nodes in the layout which seems like what you are trying to do.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I had read the function name but I didn't know you could use for each branch individually. Thanks!